# Submenu command with Voice on Card/Livecard

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have GDK app with static card and have assigned menu to it. Such as 'Watch'. Now, I can activate that menu by touching the current active card. Is there a possibility to launch that menu with voice command 'Watch' rather touching it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want contextual voice commands. These aren't supported yet, but you can follow the relevant [issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273) to stay apprised of future changes/enhancements.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to have this functionality enabled in GDK.

Comment: This now exists in the issue tracker as "Support for Contextual voice commands in GDK" at https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273 if you want to star it or add additional use cases.